# In python, how to restrict the parameter of the constructor of child class

Tags: python, constructor

I want to make an constraint on every constructor of child classes, such as the number of parameters and the type of the parameters

I am using python3

I try to use @abstractmethod, but it just block the creation of parent class so I could make child class without any restriction

is it possible? then how can i do that?

simple examples or just useful references will be grateful for me

Comment: There is no doubt something that could be done. With some effort (probably a metaclass that inspects the signature of a method, or maybe just a `__init_subclass__`) but *why*? Why isn't simply documenting what should happen sufficient?

Comment: Also, static analysis tools like `mypy` could warn about this ..